# Combining 2 websites to Magento 1.9 Multi-Store

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore

We have **two websites** both built on **Magento 1.9.**

Can we integrate both into one like creating a Multi-Store or it can be done only before developing the websites?

Answer (score 1):

That depends on a number of things:

- Are the website frontend themes identical? If so, copying them to the new server and selecting them on store level should not be a problem.
- You can import products from one store into the other, but you need to make sure the attribute sets are identical, so every attribute in the export from store A should be present in store B

Overall, it's a very complicated process, other than product and category data, you also have customer and order data to consider for example. Just make sure you know what you are doing and consider if it's worth all the trouble.

More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13572892/i-have-many-separate-installs-for-magento-can-i-merge-them-together